# Strange behavior for method default parameters initialization

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, syntax

When I am trying to initialize this it is working perfectly fine

```
class Abc
  def initialize(parent_id, user = nil, permission)
  end
end

Abc.new(1 ,2, "some_permission")
```

But when I am doing this

```
  class Abc
    def initialize(parent_id, user = nil, permission, g_data = nil)    
    end
  end
```

Abc.new(1 ,2, "some_permission", 4)

I am getting syntax error syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting ')'
This is a strange behavior why it is not taking two arguments  default as nil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to ruby [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.3/doc/syntax/methods_rdoc.html#label-Default+Values) the default values should be grouped.

> The default value does not need to appear first, but arguments with
>   defaults must be grouped together.

So according to this rule your method arguments should be listed like following:

```rb
  class Abc
    def initialize(parent_id, user = nil,g_data = nil,permission)    
    end

    # OR
    def initialize(parent_id, permission,user = nil,g_data = nil)    
    end
  end
```